# Lightning URL Hack : How to get grand Parent record values

Tags: lightning, lightning-experience

I need to fetch Parent's Parent record values to be prepopulated in my New record creation page. below URL hack is not saving/throwing error :

*Error: Field Account.Owner.Phone does not exist. Check spelling.*

Below is the URL hack that I'm trying

> /lightning/o/Contact/new?defaultFieldValues=AccountId={!Account.Id},Phone={!Account.Owner.Phone},LastName=Vamsy&navigationLocation=RELATED_LIST&backgroundContext=%2Flightning%2Fr%2FAccount%2F{!Account.Id}%2Fview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I usually solve this by creating a formula to pull the necessary data onto the account.

Owner_Phone__c would look something like this:

```
Owner.Phone
```

Then, you just update your URL hack in the following way:

```
/lightning/o/Contact/new?defaultFieldValues=AccountId={!Account.Id},Phone={!Account.Owner_Phone__c},LastName=Vamsy&navigationLocation=RELATED_LIST&backgroundContext=%2Flightning%2Fr%2FAccount%2F{!Account.Id}%2Fview
```

Comment: Thank you..!! I can see that will be the only approach left if it is not possible through the URL hack.